# OpenGL Texture 2D Draws Solid Color But Won't Draw Image

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, sdl-2

I'm attempting to draw an image on the screen using SDL and OpenGL. I try to load the image (pixel data) to a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` and draw it. However, the image is never drawn. The shape and size of the texture is drawn, but it is solid colored what my fragment shader color is set to; but the image never shows up. I have checked my code over and over and cannot find any reason why it wouldn't work. Also, `glGetError()` doesn't return any errors. If someone would help me find what I did wrong, I would greatly appreciate it!

This is the code I use to setup GL after setting up my SDL window:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);

context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

GLuint vertexShader = loadShader(vshPath, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint fragmentShader = loadShader(fshPath, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

glProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(glProgram, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(glProgram, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(glProgram);
glUseProgram(glProgram);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(position);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glGenTextures(1, textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

This is the code I use to draw the image on the screen:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0]);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

float vertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f
};

glVertexAttribPointer(position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
```

My fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float; 
void main() { 
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

My vertex shader:

```
varying vec4;
attribute vec4 position; 
void main() { 
    gl_Position = position; 
}
```

Comment: I don't follow. Why do you expect the output to be anything but a solid color if the output of your fragment shader is indeed a solid color? It sounds like you get exactly what you implemented.

Comment: Oh. I'm new to OpenGL and I didn't know that; I'm just trying to follow tutorials. How do I change my fragment shader to display the image instead of a solid color?